# Unable to select my custom keyboard from the available keyboards list

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm developing a custom keyboard app for iOS devices. After adding keyboard extension to my app I added a TextView to Main.storyboard and then I ran my app on an iPhone 5 simulator.

For adding my custom keyboard to available keyboards list I went to Settings > General > Keyboards > Add new Keyboard & here I added my custom keyboard but when I'm returning back to my app and trying to select my custom keyboard by long pressing the globe icon, my custom keyboard has not been shown there.

**What's the matter here**?

Please reply & *I'm sorry for no code as I haven't coded any yet*.

**Thanks** in advance

Please neglect the *mistakes*!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug concerning the simulator.

Either you run your extension on a real device or you can use the Photo app or Safari browser of the simulator to test your extension.

[general article about developing iOS keyboards (head for “The Simulator”)](http://beta-blog.archagon.net/2014/11/08/the-trials-and-tribulations-of-writing-a-3rd-party-ios-keyboard/)

> As of Xcode 6.1, you can no longer open 3rd party keyboards in most apps in the  Simulator, including your own. (And not just 3rd party keyboards: most system keyboards refuse to show up, too.) Not only does this make debugging a whole lot harder, but it also prevents you from easily making screenshots of your keyboard if you don’t own some of the newer devices. This issue is marked as a bug in Radar, and seeing as how it first appeared in the Xcode 6.1 betas, I cannot fathom how it got through to release.

Comment: No man, it's just not happening. Not even in Safari browser or Photo app. Do I have to enrol in Apple Developer Program & test it on a real iOS Device?